# MapInfo shapefile vs. naturalearthdata.com shapefile

Tags: shapefile, r, mapinfo

When I load this map [shapefile](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/451799/WashingtonLand%20shape%20file.zip) (exported from MapInfo as a shapefile)

```
shp.WashingtonLand<-readOGR("C:\\...\\Maps","WLmap2_polyline")
```

R replies:

```
OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
Source: "C:\Users\Andreas\SkyDrive\Speciale\02. Data\02. Statistik", layer: "WLmap2_polyline"
with 2577 features and 23 fields
Feature type: wkbLineString with 3 dimensions
Warning message:
In readOGR("C:\\Users\\Andreas\\SkyDrive\\Speciale\\02. Data\\02. Statistik",  :
  Z-dimension discarded
```

How do I see what this Z-dimension is?

Can this explain why the map won't show with points on, or as a layer on top of another shapefile like the ones from Naturalearthdata.com?

Comment: What format was the file you downloaded? TAB? SHP? Shape is an ESRI format, nothing to do with MapInfo. Also, MapInfo can't export to SHP, so I'm a little confused as to the MapInfo connection here. Have you tried opening the SHP in  QGIS or ArcGIS first to check it's valid and has points? Also, I'm not familiar with r, perhaps you need to set the projection somewhere?

Comment: I'm using the "universal translator" under Tools in MapInfo, it exports to shape (the file I linked to). Others have recommended it in here in another context, but there is some difference apparently that is causing my problem

Comment: Not so many versions ago, Universal Translator always exported to SHP files with Z-values, despite TAB files never have Z-values. You need to do the conversion with something else, if you want to avoid z-values. Ogr2ogr, never version of MapInfo etc.

Comment: yes, I found that QGIS would convert the tab -> shp without that z-value. Unfortunately this did not fix my problem, but I will (probably) write another question for that after some more testing. Thanks BStone og tak til Uffe :-)